# siunitx: Bracket Around Some Units

Tags: siunitx

Writing a paper and am trying to figure out how to recreate the industry standard for spectral efficiency units. The standard is to use "(bits\s)\Hz" for the units. Is there anyway to recreate this in `siunitx`? Currently, I get "bits(s Hz)".

Comment: Not at present: as far as `siunitx` is concerned, that's `bits/(s Hz)`  or `bits s^{-1} Hz^{-1}`, i.e. there is no 'grouping' of units. I do have an open feature request in a somewhat similar area: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/577.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how in general one would decide where the brackets go here: group only the first reciprocal unit, group all but the last one, ..

Comment: Honestly, as this is a weird request, I'd go with the "here's enough rope..." route and let the end user manually set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present 'no, you'll have to format this manually

```latex
\unit{(\mathrm{bits}.\mathrm{s})/\mathrm{Hz}}
```

Comment: Appreciate the absurdly quick response.